# Getting the list of Instance IDs from Auto Scale in EC2 service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

Is there a way to send in SQS message the list of Spawned "scaled" instances configured to launch by Auto Scale service of EC2 ?

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand. Could you please clarify your requirements? For example: Do you want an SQS message every time that an instance is launched into an Auto Scaling group, or just a single message listing all instances in the group "right now"? Why do you want it via an SQS message -- would you be willing to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or an API call? Feel free to Edit your question to add detail.

Comment: my use case is Monte Carlo Sim. I want to map different inputs files contained in a folder in S3 to an instance. I figured, I need to use instance Id to rename the folder, so that way an instance will only use inputs files contained in a folder that has the same name as the instance Id. I understand this is a hack, but bash processing differ form MCS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the Instance ID of an ec2 instance during a scaling event you can set up Lifecycle hooks with SQS.

> Receive Notification Using Amazon SQS
>
> You can use Amazon SQS to set up a notification target to receive notifications when a lifecycle action occurs.
>
> To set up notifications using Amazon SQS
>
> 1. Create the target using Amazon SQS. For more information, see Getting Started with Amazon SQS in the Amazon Simple Queue Service Developer Guide. Note the ARN of the target.
> 2. Create an IAM role to grant Auto Scaling permission to access your notification target, using the steps in Creating a Role to Delegate Permissions to an AWS Service in the IAM User Guide. When prompted to select a role type, select AWS Service Roles, AutoScaling Notification Access. Note the ARN of the role. For example, arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-notification-role.
> 3. When Auto Scaling responds to a scale out or scale in event, it puts the instance in a wait state. While the instance is in a wait state, Auto Scaling publishes a message to the notification target.

Example Message:

```
Service: AWS Auto Scaling
Time: 2016-09-30T20:42:11.305Z
RequestId: 18b2ec17-3e9b-4c15-8024-ff2e8ce8786a
LifecycleActionToken: 71514b9d-6a40-4b26-8523-05e7ee35fa40
AccountId: 123456789012
AutoScalingGroupName: my-asg
LifecycleHookName: my-hook
EC2InstanceId: i-0598c7d356eba48d7
LifecycleTransition: autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING
NotificationMetadata: null
```

Then Add Lifecycle Hook

You can create lifecycle hooks using the put-lifecycle-hook command.

To perform an action on scale out, use the following command:

```
aws autoscaling put-lifecycle-hook --lifecycle-hook-name my-hook --auto-scaling-group-name my-asg --lifecycle-transition autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING --notification-target-arn arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:my-sqs --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-notification-role
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html#adding-lifecycle-hooks

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/put-lifecycle-hook.html

Comment: Excellent, I suppose the SQS message will have a list of launched instances ID "EC2InstanceId" if the autoscaling is done over multitude of instances ?

Comment: It will have a new message for each scaling event that occurs with each I'd in them.  So you'll want to make to delete messages after you parse them.

Comment: It can get expensive, if one has 1k to 10k instances to launch. Tnks. Note AWS will accommodate this scaling option

Comment: Price per 1 Million Requests after Free Tier (Monthly)
Standard Queue
$0.40 ($0.00000040 per request)
https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/